# Upload multiple files with dynamic form data bound to each file using multer, ng-file-upload, angular and node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, upload, multer, ng-file-upload

I’m using angular, and ng-file-upload on the client side.  I’m using node, express, and multer on the server side.

When a user selects multiple files, I show a preview of the files along with a textarea that is bound to the model.  This purpose of the text area is to provide the user with the ability to give each uploaded file a note/description.

When I call ng-file-upload’s upload function and pass in the model of the files, I see that the dynamic form data specific to each file is present on the array that is being uploaded.

On the server side I am using multer.  Everything seems functions properly.  I am able to upload multiple files, however the dynamic form data is not available on multer’s built in req.files object and I do not know where I can access the dynamic data.

I have searched through the request object and could not find the data I was looking for.

How can I add dynamic data to each file individually and pass it to the server and have access to it?

Client

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(files) {
     console.log('files', files); //I see that this argument contains the user input as property ‘Desc’
    if (files && files.length) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/filesinorg/upload/'+ $rootScope.currentUser.primary_org_id,
            arrayKey: '', // default is '[i]'
            data: {
                files: files,
                fileData: {
                    Organization_id: $rootScope.currentUser.primary_org_id,
                    uploadBy_id: $rootScope.currentUser._id
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.filesSelected = [];
                $scope.uploadedFiles.push(result.data.files);
            });
        }, function (result) {
            if (result.status > 0) {
                $scope.errorMsg = result.status + ': ' + result.data;
            }
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }
};
```

Server

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var uploadPath = '';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/'+ req.params.orgId + '/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
var uploadRoot = 'uploads/';
function checkUploadPath(req, res, next) {
    var orgId = req.params.orgId;
    uploadPath =uploadRoot + orgId + '/';
    fs.stat(uploadPath, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
            fs.mkdir(uploadPath, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('Error in folder creation');
                    next();
                }
                next();
            });
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    });
}



var type = upload.array('files');
    router.use('/filesinorg/upload/:orgId', checkUploadPath, type);
    router.route('/filesinorg/upload/:orgId')
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var orgId = req.params.orgId;
            var filesUploaded = req.files;
            var fileData = req.body.fileData;
            var isError = false;
            var filesSaved = [];

            filesUploaded.forEach(function(file) {
                console.log('file', file);
                console.log('file.Desc', file.Desc);
                var newFile = new File();
                newFile.fileName = file.originalname;
                newFile.serverPath = file.path;
                newFile.shortDesc = file.Desc.slice(0,20);
                newFile.Desc = file.Desc;
                newFile.upload_dt = Date.now();
                newFile.uploadBy_id = fileData.uploadBy_id;
                newFile.Organization_id = fileData.Organization_id;
                newFile.type = file.mimetype;

                file.save(function(err, savedFile) {
                    if (err) {
                        return isError = true;
                    }

                    filesSaved.push(newFile);
                    console.log('File Saved success fully');
                });
            });

            if(isError) {
                res.status(500).send({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'Error Saving File',
                    file: null
                })
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    success: true,
                    msg: 'Saved Contact',
                    files: filesSaved
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: My solution was to build completely separate objects with all the data I wanted then save the data on the same request.  Either multer or ng-file-upload was converting my array of objects I created on the client side into a single object with arrays for each field value.  So I also had to stringify my object on the client and parse it on the server. I'm not sure this was the best way to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in same scenario where I needed to send multiple files with their names and size .
You can use Use closure function which can act as middle man who have access to global as well as local variable  and also immediate local variables.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question or is related to the question.